# Is automatic dependency injection available in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I want to automatically dependency inject an Angular built-in service into all services within an Angular module / app.

The service I want to inject is ... $exceptionHandler

I **do not want** $exceptionHandler to be global ... e.g. I **do not want** to do ...

```
window.$exceptionHandler = $exceptionHandler
```

But I also **do not want** to dependency inject $exceptionHandler into every service manually using ...

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('myService', ['$exceptionHandler', function ($exceptionHandler) {
```

Is it possible to automatically inject an Angular built-in service into all services within an Angular module / app ?

Many thanks

Comment: No. Because dependency injection design rejects ideas like your ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be made more convenient through nested modules. In the root (or global) module inject $exceptionHandler and all the other modules you create or want to use. All sub modules of the root module will have $exceptionHandler injected without further ado. You still have to name the $exceptionHandler in your controller and factory function definitions, though, so it is not possible to completely get rid of injection artefacts.

Example:

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', '$exceptionHandler', 'ngCordova','app.home',
'app.impressum'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $state) {
   ..
})
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $provide, $exceptionHandler, $ionicConfigProvider, $compileProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            ...
        })
    }
);
```

Now the app.home-Module:

**home.js**

```
angular.module('app.home', ['app.home.controller', 'app.home.factory']);
```

**home/controller.js**

```
angular.module('app.home.controller', [])
  .controller('homeController', function ($scope, $exceptionHandler) {
    ...
  });
```

*app.home.factory* and the three modules for *app.impressum* are quite similar, so I leave that to you.

As you can see you still have to put $exceptionHandler into the function parameters of your controller, but no injection is required on the module itself, because it inherits all injections from it's parent modules *app.home* and *app*.

By using a hierarchy of modules in an AngularJS app injections can be made where due... more globally for the whole app, for module groups or only on single modules. Plus we get a very clean structure for the App's sections.